# Pandas remove duplicates with condition from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'case_id': [1050, 1050, 1050, 1050, 1051, 1051, 1051, 1051],
    'elm_id': [101, 102, 101, 102, 101, 102, 101, 102],
    'cid': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'fx': [736.1, 16.5, 98.8, 158.5, 272.5, 750.0, 333.4, 104.2],
    'fy': [992.0, 261.3, 798.3, 452.0, 535.9, 838.8, 526.7, 119.4],
    'fz': [428.4, 611.0, 948.3, 523.9, 880.9, 340.3, 890.7, 422.1]})
```

When printed looks like this:

`---  case_id  cid  elm_id  fx     fy     fz
0     1050    1     101  736.1  992.0  428.4
1     1050    1     102   16.5  261.3  611.0
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
4     1051    1     101  272.5  535.9  880.9
5     1051    1     102  750.0  838.8  340.3
6     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
7     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1`

I need to remove rows where duplicate values exist in the following two columns `subcase` and `elm_id` and retain the row with the highest `cid`. The data should look like this:

`---  case_id  cid  elm_id  fx     fy     fz
0     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
1     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
2     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
3     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1`

I'm new to pandas. Looking at other similar questions, I tried using `.groupby()` and `max()` like this: `df2 = df.groupby(['case_id', 'elm_id']).max()['cid'].reset_index()`. However I lost my columns `fx`, `fy` and `fz`. I feel like I'm close, I just don't know where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values('cid', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['case_id', 'elm_id'])

   case_id  cid  elm_id     fx     fy     fz
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
6     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
7     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1
```

Comment: This looks promising. However, I'm using pandas 0.15.2 which does not have method `sort_values`. I'm not sure if I can upgrade my pandas version behind my work firewall. Looking into it now...

Comment: @twegner try replacing `sort_values` by `df.sort('cid', axis=1, ascending=False)`?

Comment: `raise ValueError('When sorting by column, axis must be 0 (rows)`. So changing to `axis=0` made it work. Thanks!

Comment: @twegner That is just so dumb. Now I know why they dropped the API, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to this:

```
df[(df.duplicated(subset=['subcase','elm_id']))&(df['cid']>1)]

   case_id  cid  elm_id     fx     fy     fz
2     1050    2     101   98.8  798.3  948.3
3     1050    2     102  158.5  452.0  523.9
6     1051    2     101  333.4  526.7  890.7
7     1051    2     102  104.2  119.4  422.1
```

Comment: Only works because cid takes two values here: 1 and 2. Not a good approach in general.